# Tensorflow -- how can I process in numpy op outputs in py_func gradient?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, gradient

I used this link: https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342 to create a py_func function with gradient.. Here is the code by Harpone:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import numpy as np

def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0,1e+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc" : rnd_name}):
       return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

def mysquare(x, name=None):
   with ops.op_scope([x], name, "Mysquare") as name:
       sqr_x = py_func(np.square, [x], [tf.float32], name=name, grad=_MySquareGrad)
       return sqr_x[0]

def _MySquareGrad(op, grad):
   x = op.inputs[0] // how can I process this op.inputs[0] in numpy??
   return x*grad*2 // sample gradient

with tf.Session() as sess:
   x = tf.constant([8., 2.])
   y = mysquare(x)

tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

print (x.eval(), y.eval(), tf.gradients(y,x)[0].eval())
```

My question is, I can retrieve my layer's inputs and outputs by using op.input[0] for the first input and op.output[0] for the first output.

But what I get from op.output[0] is a Tensor which I want to process in python using numpy... Is there any way that I can convert this Tensor into numpy within the python gradient environment of py_func?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tf.py_func`
IE, to square `x` using numpy

```
def _MySquareGrad(op, grad):
   x = op.inputs[0] # how can I process this op.inputs[0] in numpy??
   xx = tf.py_func(np.square, [x], [tf.float32])
   return xx[0]*grad*2 # sample gradient
```